# Python: Dos to Unix '\n' characters at the end of sentences

Tags: python

I am working with a Python script that takes files from Windows but works the script in a Ubuntu Virtual Box. I have found that the problem with my code is the `\r\n` characters at the end of sentences. I have managed to remove the `\r` by:

```
f = open(file_path, 'rU')
```

Is there a similar way to remove the `\n` characters? Or are they no problem?

Comment: If you remove the "\n"s then how will you tell one line from the next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [PEP 278](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/node7.html) Opening file with the mode 'U' or 'rU' opens a file for reading in universal newline mode this implies
`f = open(file_path, 'rU')`
should work fine on Ubuntu or any platform.

Answer (score 1):

The \n characters are your newlines. \r\n in Windows should map to \n in Unix.

You could remove the newlines with regex if you want. But this is not normally what you would want.